# Python Pandas: How to replace values in a Dataframe based on another array in conditional base

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a DataFrame as follows. Both columns have Member_ID which indicates which Member_ID connected with other Member_ID

```
   col1  col2
    1     3
    1     4
    1     5
    2     3
    2     4
    3     1
    3     2
    3     5
    4     1
    4     2
    5     1
    5     3
```

and I have calculated each Member_ID connected with how many Member_ID. For example Member_ID 1 is connected with 3 Member_ID. If an Member_ID contains more or equal to 3 connections we have to put "a" in front of the Member_Id else we have to put "b" so the label we have to give the label as "a1" for Member_ID 1.
Likewise I have calculated the labels for each Member_Id and the label array is below.

```
 member_ID   No_of_con  Label
    1          3         a1
    2          2         b2
    3          3         a3
    4          2         b4
    5          2         b5
```

Now I have to replace the first Dataframe's values referring from the label array. Dataframe is big for using for loops is not efficient So how can i achive this using Pandas in simpler way? I'm expecting the result as below

```
    col1     col2
    a1         a3
    a1         b4
    a1         b5
    b2         a3
    b2         b4
    a3         a1
    a3         b2
    a3         b5
    b4         a1
    b4         b2
    b5         a1
    b5         a3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can `stack`, `map` and `unstack`:

```
In [9]: d1.stack().map(d2.set_index('member_ID')['Label']).unstack()
Out[9]:
   col1 col2
0    a1   a3
1    a1   b4
2    a1   b5
3    b2   a3
4    b2   b4
5    a3   a1
6    a3   b2
7    a3   b5
8    b4   a1
9    b4   b2
10   b5   a1
11   b5   a3
```

Comment: @kumaranragunathan, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this

```
df2.set_index('member_ID',inplace=True)
df1.apply(lambda x: x.map(df2['Label']))


   col1 col2
0    a1   a3
1    a1   b4
2    a1   b5
3    b2   a3
4    b2   b4
5    a3   a1
6    a3   b2
7    a3   b5
8    b4   a1
9    b4   b2
10   b5   a1
11   b5   a3
```

Comment: we can also use `.applymap()` - it looks like it got faster in latest Pandas versions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.replace` using a `pd.Series` in a dictionary context.

```
d1.replace(d2.set_index('member_ID').Label)

   col1 col2
0    a1   a3
1    a1   b4
2    a1   b5
3    b2   a3
4    b2   b4
5    a3   a1
6    a3   b2
7    a3   b5
8    b4   a1
9    b4   b2
10   b5   a1
11   b5   a3
```