# Python: How to write lists with different length to a .txt file with correct format as display when print on python.

Tags: list, python-3.x, file

[Python Pandas: How to replace values in a Dataframe based on another array in conditional base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389499/python-pandas-how-to-replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-another-array-in-co) 
For the same problem as above question, If I want to make them as list like following code to list them.

```
 z=d1.stack().map(d2.set_index('member_ID')['Label']).unstack()    
 rstlist=z.groupby('member_ID')['Label'].apply(list) 
 print(rstlist)
```

I can display the list on python screen as below.

```
 member_ID
 a1    [a3, b4, b5]
 a3    [a1, b2, b5]
 b2        [a3, b4]
 b4        [a1, b2]
 b5        [a1, a3]
 Name: Label, dtype: object
```

I need to write those lists into any .txt file, and I tried following code.

```
np.savetxt('tst_net.dat', rstlist.values, fmt='%s', delimiter="\t",     
     header="member_ID\t\tConnectedTo")
```

Although it write the file, the format is as below.

```
# member_ID     ConnectedTo
 ['a3', 'b4', 'b5']
 ['a1', 'b2', 'b5']
 ['a3', 'b4']
 ['a1', 'b2']
 ['a1', 'a3']
```

But, I need to write it to a .txt file as it display on the screen.

```
 member_ID    Connected_to
 a1    [a3, b4, b5]
 a3    [a1, b2, b5]
 b2        [a3, b4]
 b4        [a1, b2]
 b5        [a1, a3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
for key, value in rstlist.items():
     thefile.write("%s\t%s\n" % (key, value))
```

Comment: Thank you Kumaran. It's perfect answer.

Comment: glad to help you..!